# Groupby and having in web2py

Tags: web2py

my table:

```
db.define_table('test', Field('name'), Field('pics', 'upload'))
```

I want to display 5 names from the `name` randomly, then I want to display one picture from the `pics` that has a matching id with any one of the randomly selected names.

This is the action:

```
def index():
    rows = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>')
    myorder = rows==id
    rows_two = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 1), groupby=db.test.pics, having=myorder)
    return locals()
```

and this is the view:

```
{{for i in rows_two:}}
<div style="text-align:left">
<img width="200px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=i.pics)}}" />
</div>
{{pass}}
{{block left_sidebar}}
{{for row in rows:}}
{{=LI(A(row.name, _href=URL('other', args=row.id)))}}
{{pass}}
{{end}}
```

What I want to achieve is to display one image from `pics` that's id matches with one of the randomly displayed names. Of course, this is not working, so I'd appreciate some help with this. Thanks very much.

Comment: Why do you need the second query? Can't you just display the pic from the first record in `rows` (or from any record in `rows`)?

Comment: @Anthony Yes, I tried to display the image and the names from the first record in `rows` but I couldn't figure out how display 5 `name` and 1 `pics`, I tried `limitby=(0,5)` and `limitby=(0,1)` in the same query but I just couldn't get it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like there is no need for `rows_two`, as each of the records in `rows` already contains a pic, so you can just use any one of those. So, change your code to the following:

```
def index():
    rows = db().select(db.test.ALL, limitby=(0, 5), orderby='<random>')
    return locals()
```

In the view:

```
<div style="text-align:left">
<img width="200px"
     src="{{=URL('download', args=rows[0].pic)}}" />
</div>
```

Note, the view simply displays the pic from the first record in `rows`.

Comment: thanks very much. I need to understand `args` better and you are helping me a lot. I appreciate it. BTW: is there a way to use `random` in the view in a way that the image will be displayed randomly from the records in `rows`, not only always from the first record?

Comment: I can't believe it, but I think I figured out the answer to my question in my previous comment. This is what I did in the `view`: 
`{{import random k=random.randint(0, 4)}}` then `src="{{=URL('download', args=rows[k].pics)}}"`. Now the image is displayed randomly from the records in `rows` instead of displaying the first record. Is this the right way? It seems to be working. Then, I guess I am making some progress! Thanks to you!

Comment: I am running into a new problem. Now I have 5 random `name` displayed and 1 random `pics`, the 1 `pics` has the same id as one of the five `name`. If the `name` that matches the `pics` is clicked I want to do something in the `other` action, basically saying right answer and if any of the other 4 `name` clicked I want to do something else, basically saying wrong answer in the `other` action. I tried just about everything to make this happen but failed. Should I post this in a separate question, or can you help me with this here?